# How to write at last index of file in write mode in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I want to write data in file at the end of every call. How can I do this in iOS? Below are the steps.

1. If "filename" doesn't exist create a new file
2. And write NSData or Data content in the file.
3. Next time when thread complete the work it will again call same method to write in file but if file exist it will open to write from last index in file.
4. I don't want to store or cache data in memory to write simultaneously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append new string to txt file in swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736215/append-new-string-to-txt-file-in-swift-2)

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the documentation of [Filehandle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle).

Create a file handle, then `seekToEndOfFile()` before using `write(_ data: Data)`.